# what's the difference between iret and iretd,iretq?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86

I want to simulate a iret condition on a Linux x86_64 server.
I found there are three instructions

1. iret:operand size 16
2. iretd:operand size 32
3. iretq:operand size 64

I can't tell the difference of them,and which one to use.
thanks for anyone's help!!

I have another question about simulate iret,can you have a look?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756274/how-to-simulate-a-iret-on-linux-x86-64

Comment: They are all the same opcode, 0xcf.  IRETQ has the REX.W prefix for 64-bit code.  What you do depends on the mode of the processor and the mode of the code that was interrupted.  Not easily simulated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From this [link](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref-iret.html):

> IRET returns from an interrupt (hardware or software) by means of
>   popping IP (or EIP), CS, and the flags off the stack and then
>   continuing execution from the new CS:IP.
>
> IRETW pops IP, CS and the flags as 2 bytes each, taking 6 bytes off
>   the stack in total. IRETD pops EIP as 4 bytes, pops a further 4 bytes
>   of which the top two are discarded and the bottom two go into CS, and
>   pops the flags as 4 bytes as well, taking 12 bytes off the stack.
>
> IRET is a shorthand for either IRETW or IRETD, depending on the
>   default BITS setting at the time.

Very similar is also for IRETQ

Comment: IOW, `IRET` will correctly return from an ISR in the current CPU mode in most cases. Special cases may require `IRETW/D/Q`, which will insert the appropriate instruction prefix.

Comment: I have another question about simulate iret,can you have a look?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756274/how-to-simulate-a-iret-on-linux-x86-64